# create an installable component library like shadcn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm making a design system and I would like to know how I could make an installable library like shadcn does, I would like to have the source code of the components installed in my project in case I want to change something

I would like to know if there is a tool for this

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for npm.

By bundling your components as a npm package, others can install and import those into their project and even patch the source code if required.

Comment: I published the design system in a package on npm, but I don't know how I could get the component's source code to stay in my project, shadcn uses npx add to download the components for example

Comment: You can include your source code in you NPM package and actually this is a common practice (e.g., typescript libraries).